# Writing to text files using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, excel, file, path, savefiledialog

I'm working on an Add In for Microsoft Excel in Visual Studio that records the balances for each account (or Worksheet) and saves them to a user-specified file. The ability to press a button and select a destination to save your work is an essential skill for any programmer, so I'm perplexed as to why there is so little information on how to do it. The closest thing I found was a tutorial on MSDN that saves a button icon image.

The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (ThisAddIn.createdbudget)
{
    string budget = "Budget = " + ThisAddIn.blake.budget;

    SaveFileDialog savebudget = new SaveFileDialog();
    savebudget.Filter = "Data files (*.dat)|*.dat|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    savebudget.Title = "Save Budget";
    savebudget.ShowDialog();

    if (savebudget.FileName != "")
    {
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(savebudget.OpenFile()))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(budget);
        }
    }
}

else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Control disabled.  Budget does not yet exist.");
}
```

My objective is to allow the user to designate a file path via `SaveFileDialog` and save a new .dat (or .txt).  The stream writer would record the account names and their respective balances line by line. Something like:

```
sr.WriteLine(Account1.Name + " Balance = " + Account1.Balance);
sr.WriteLine(Account2.Name + " Balance = " + Account2.Balance);
etc...
```

I know this sounds complicated.  I have no problem saving data if I'm using a predetermined file path, but that's not very helpful.  What I need to know is how to properly write files using `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: so, what is the question?  Looks like a perfectly valid way to do it.  Maybe not the best way, but there is no one way to do it.

Comment: But what is your problem? The code you are showing does exactly that, let the user select a file and write to it (except that you should compare if(saveBudget.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)).

Comment: If you are missing the part about save the data look at this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: The code does indeed create and/or save the file.  When I go to open the .dat or .txt file, it's still blank, which tells me the stream writer isn't writing properly.